# simple SQL query to write in Complicated Laravel language

Tags: sql, laravel

what I needt is something as SIMPLE as this

```
select fname, lname, mobile
from users, 
join contacts
on users.id = contacts.id
where users.id = 25
```

but written in the ABSTRUSE AND COMPLICATED LANGUAGE OF LARAVEL

```
$users = DB::select('select * from users where id = ?', array($id));
```

i dont know how to continue writing the join with the contacts table just as I did above in simple, clear and healthy straight SQL.

I have tried for a full day and I have gone through the 192 pages of the booklet. There is not a single example where it shows queries for joins but that can printed as objects.

With that simple line I have no problem in sending the result to the view and print it like this:

```
return View::make('account.manageusers', compact('users'));

@foreach ($users as $user)
                <tr>
          <td>{{ $user->fname }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->lname }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->mobile }}</td>
```

but the problem is that I dont know how to write the full query of the joins in whatever Laravel orm or god knows what that is, so I cant print it if I dont have the query properly set.

thanks a lot if you know how to.

regards

Comment: Laravel is not a language, it is a PHP Framework.  You should read up on Laravel relationships to see if that could make your syntax more elegant. However, you can also run [raw queries](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions) in Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either write it as a raw query like the DB::select() statement or use the [query builder's joins](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins) and you'll receive a stdClass object back.  If you want you can use it on an Eloquent model with the same syntax, but starting with `Model::join()`

Comment: Hello, I know that snippet of query builder but as I indicated, then you cannot print it as object -> notation, and I want it like that, otherwise I have to modified the full View page

Comment: I tried this (of course changing the names) 
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.id', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price'); but then you cannot print it as I have it

Comment: You have to use ->get() at the end to fetch from the database.

Comment: Ok, I cannot try it now but I have the feeling you are right, you sound knowledgeable. I ll give you the correct answer now and will tell you tomorrow. thank you and god bless you

Answer (score 0):

User::join("contacts","users.id","=","contacts")->select(["fname", "lname", "mobile"])->where("users.id", 25)->get()

Comment: Some explanation would greatly improve the quality of the answer and help other users who may encounter similar problems in the future
Please take some time to read the help page [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)